# Express/MongoDB/EJS - Can't read object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

So I Have some data in my Mongo Database, which I`.find()` by express and send it to my EJS view. pretty simple. But the problem is when I try to read it using `<pre><%=%></pre>` i get undefined. Here's the entire code:

**The Data Array containing Object in MongoDB:**

```js
[{
  _id: 6069820f402d01120cda8cff,
  imageName: 'Dining Plate',
  imagePath: './public/assets/img/6.jpg',
  description: 'Wallpapers',
  __v: 0
}]
```

Express Code where I get it and send it to EJS:

```js
app.get('/wallpapers/:id', ((req, res) => {
  const urlID = req.params.id;
  Thing.find({}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var fres = result.filter(d => d._id == urlID);
      res.render('wallpaper-page',{fres});
    }
  });
})
)
```

and the EJS:

```html
<pre><%= fres.description%> %> </pre>
```

And Now the BIG CONFUSION: when I replace `fres.description` with `fres._id`, It works perfectly fine. but that's it, it doesn't wanna print any other key values. I've been searching far and wide for almost a day now. But nothing helps. this is annoying me now.

**PS:** `console.log(fres.description)` is `undefined` and `console.log(fres._id)` works fine.

Why? How do I fix this?
please tell me if you need any other code.

Comment: If you have to search by id, why don't you simply use `Thing.findById(req.params.id)`. Can you also tell what is does `console.log(fres)` give?

Comment: findbyid will still give me the object. console.log(fres) gives me the object too.`{
  _id: 6069820f402d01120cda8cff,
  imageName: 'Dining Plate',
  imagePath: './public/assets/img/6.jpg',
  description: 'Wallpapers',
  __v: 0
}`

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, let me know if it helps. @lolman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the problem with the filter method returns an array, I think you have another problem accessing data from Mongoose response.

This problem is discussed here: [Mongoose return data inside _doc object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989100/mongoose-return-data-inside-doc-object/66944141#66944141). You can check out my answer with a test code to demonstrate some methods to access data from Mongoose response.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I discovered myself and used .lean with .findOne which fixed it. I was just about to post it here and found this.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.filter` returns an array. So, `var fres = result.filter(d => d._id == urlID);` the variable `fres` is an array with an object in it.

And if you need only the object in your EJS template, you need to pass just that.
`res.render('wallpaper-page',{fres: fres[0]});`

Now you can access the `description` key directly. But I don't understand how `fres._id` works, it should also be `undefined`.

Comment: Oh Sorry! I made a silly mistake, it should be `{fres: fres[0]}` @lolman Try this.

Comment: I created another varible with its value as `fres[0]` and passed it to the view. I still got undefined and ._id works edit: ok  Edit2: the problem still persists :(

Comment: Is this the problem `<pre><%= fres.description%> %> </pre>` You're closing it twice.

Comment: Where are you exactly logging `fres`? Log it after the `filter` method.