# _doc in request body

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs

I am trying to send an object created by MongoDB model as a body of post request in a jest test.
Here is the test:

```
test("post request successfully creates a new blog", async () => {
  const newBlog = new Blog({
    title: "My mundane day at home 3",
    author: "AbG",
    url: "https://www.google.co.in/",
    likes: 11,
  });
  await api
    .post("/api/blogs")
    .send(newBlog)
    .expect(201)
    .expect("Content-Type", /application\/json/)
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  const blogs = await Blog.find({});
  expect(blogs).toHaveLength(initialBlogs.length + 1);
});
```

As you can see, I am sending the newBlog as a body of request. But when I receive it in controller, the newBlog is present in the request.body._doc instead of request.body.
I think this has something to do with the mongoose model of blog.

```
const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  url: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
    default: 0,
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);
```

I cannot understand why this is happening.

Comment: Is this discussion respond to your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989100/mongoose-return-data-inside-doc-object

Comment: ĐăngKhoaĐinh the question had a similar issue as mine. Although the solution was not the same, I managed to find the solution. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where I was going wrong.
In the test case, I was creating a mongodb schema instance and passing it as body of request instead of a plain JS object. And in the express app, I was trying to access the request body as a JS object. So that created a confusion.
The changes that I did:
In test:
Instead of

```
const newBlog = new Blog({....})
```

I did

```
const newBlog = {....}
```

So, I avoided passing mongodb object as request body and created the mongodb object using the constructor immediately before where I needed it.
Here is the post route:

```
blogsRouter.post("/", async (request, response) => {
  const blog = new Blog(request.body);
  const savedBlog = await blog.save();
  response.status(201).json(savedBlog);
});
```